# Why does the token metadata program have an account discriminator field?

Tags: anchor, mpl-token-metadata

The first field for the MetadataAccount struct is `key` which is commented as being the account discriminator.

What is MPL token metadata using this field for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MPL Token Metadata program works with [several types of accounts](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts) not just the `Metadata Account`, so it needs a simple way to determine what type a certain account is.

One common pattern to do this is to use a field as a discriminator that works as a key/id that represents the type. [Anchor does the same thing under the hood](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_bts/discriminator.html) and the documentation explains the benefits of this approach.